# A vector of strings in pure C

Tags: c, arrays, string, vector

In C++, here is how I would fill a vector of strings (each of them can have length from 1 to 65536), and iterate over it:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
std::string s = "Hello1";
v.push_back(s);
std::string s2 = "ALongerHello2";
v.push_back(s2);
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    cout << v[i];
```

I'm trying to convert it in pure C. I was thinking about using a:

```
char **v;
```

but then, how do I keep track of the beginning of each string? Should I use a separate array for storing the offset of each string in the memory space?

**More generally, how to create a vector of strings in C?**

Comment: What do you mean "the begining of each string"? That's what a `char*` points at for a C-string. You already have it.

Comment: Would you clarify your post?

Comment: @StoryTeller i'll try to rephrase (or maybe I'll read the answers first, it might answer it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach you've taken seems reasonable enough. You have a pointer to a pointer here. There's no need to keep track of the beginning of each string, since `v` is used for exactly that purpose. You'll have `v[0]` pointing to the first string, `v[1]` to the second etc.

Your example from above can look like:

```
char** v = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*2);
v[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*7);
strcpy(v[0], "Hello1");
v[1] = malloc(sizeof(char)*14);
strcpy(v[1], "ALongerHello2");
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    printf("%s", v[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Last thing: what should I do when a 3rd string has to be added? `realloc(v, sizeof(char*)*3);` or something like that?

Comment: @Basj yes that would be a way to go about it. But if you expect you'll be adding a lot to it, it's worth it to allocate a bigger size, and only reallocate when you run out of space in `v`.

Comment: Ok I'll do that with a *2 pattern (or *1.5 pattern). If 2 array is full, allocate 4, then 8, 16, 32, etc. to avoid too many realloc. Do you think the syntax `realloc(v, sizeof(char*)*3);` is correct?

Comment: @Basj that sounds good. The syntax [seems to be ok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc), though you might need to cast `v` to `(void*)v`

Comment: An array of arrays would be `char arrarr[2][3]`. A `char **v` is a pointer to a pointer. It's beneficial to make the distinction as a pointer to pointer has other uses than a lookup table as well, and a true array of arrays is contiguous, where as a "lookup table" is not.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: http://eddmann.com/posts/implementing-a-dynamic-vector-array-in-c/

> How do I keep track of the beginning of each string?

You do not have to worry about that. Each string is represented by a `char *` which is actually a pointer to the beginning of each string.

> Should I use a separate array for storing the offset of each string in the memory space?

You mentioned a `char **`. When implemeting a vector, this `char **` will point to a memory space where your `char *`s will be stored. Each of these will be a pointer to the beginning of each string. So let's imagine you have a `char **myVector` and you fill it with some strings (see link below). Then you can access the first string of the vector like so : `myVector[0]`. And you can access the first character of the first string of the vector by doing `myVector[0][0]`.

Take a look at [this link](http://eddmann.com/posts/implementing-a-dynamic-vector-array-in-c/) for a clean vector implementation in C. As you will see, it's a just a matter of pointers, dynamic memory allocation, re-allocation and `NULL` pointers checking !

Comment: `char **` is not an array of `char *`, it is a pointer to a `char *`

Answer (score 0):

C is not the best language for strings or vectors. However, there are many solutions for this problem. Your idea works fine, but you need to use `malloc` to allocate memory to your vector.

```
char** v;
int vect_dim = some_value; // the number of strings in your vector (its dimension)
int str_length = some_other_value ; // the number of characters in your string

v = malloc(sizeof(char*) * vect_dim);

v[0] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * str_length * vect_dim)
for (int i=0; i<vect_dim; i++)
    v[i] = v[0] + i*str_length;
```

**Remark:** you can have strings of different lengths in your vector but this is strong depreciated as you would probably deal with a lot of `Segmentation fault` errors.

A good practice would be defining a type and throwing all this in a function

```
typedef char **string_vector;
string_vector initialize_vector (int vect_dim, int str_length) {
    string_vector v;
    /* same code as above */
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Hum, I'm sure there is a way with non-fixed lengths (I need that because I don't want to waste 65536 for each small string) and no `Segmentation fault`.

Comment: There is a way, instead of the `for` loop I have used you give different lengths to each `v[i]`, I said _probably_ have errors but if you're careful enough you can avoid them.